# Migrations applied but no migration folder

Tags: django

I have developed a Django 1.8 project a while ago. I deployed the project a few months back and everything was running perfectly. Today, I had to make a change in the database, but when I tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations`, I got the message "No changes detected". I then noticed that there was no migration folder in any of the apps of the project. What I don't understand is:

- I made the migrations (`makemigrations` then `migrate`) when I first deployed the project, and everything was ok. I didn't check that the migration folders were there though.
- I didn't made any change to the database since this first migration and didn't remove any folder.

When I run `python manage.py showmigrations`, I get the following:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

This is the full output. No sign of any of my apps.

So my questions are the following:

- How is it possible that the migrations were made, the tables were created, etc. but no migration folder was created ?
- Where do I go from here ? I want to make the new migrations but almost all methods reinitializing migrations include the steps 'delete migrations folders'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apps are allowed to have no migrations. Only apps with a `migrations/__init__.py` file are considered to have migrations. `manage.py makemigrations` won't create migrations for unmigrated apps unless you explicitly pass the app name. On Django 1.7/1.8, the tables are still created automatically through the old syncdb mechanism -- starting on Django 1.9, this requires the `--syncdb` flag when migrating.

Now you need to get your migrations in sync with your database. For this, you need to:

1. Revert all model changes you made after initially running `manage.py migrate`.
2. Run `manage.py makemigrations <app_label>` to create an initial migration that matches your current database.
3. Run `manage.py migrate --fake-initial <app_label>` to mark the new migration as applied.

After running these steps for each app your migrations should be in sync with your database, so you can now edit your models and create new migrations.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so so much. Very nice solution that enabled me to keep all the data. I forgot the migrations folders were created with `startapp`, and since I do not include them in git, I didn't have them when pulling to the server...